T/F: For $A_\lambda$ with $\lambda>0$ converging to $\cap A_\lambda$, $\sup_{f\in A_\lambda}|f(x)|$ converging to $\sup_{f\in \cap A_\lambda}|f(x)|$
Let $X$ be a Banach space and $f$ be a bounded linear functional defined on $X$. Consider a monotonically decreasing net $\{A_\lambda\}_\lambda$ with $\lambda>0$ such that $A_\lambda$ converging to $\bigcap A_\lambda$ then can I conclude that $\displaystyle\sup_{f\in A_\lambda}|f(x)|$ converging to $\displaystyle\sup_{f\in \bigcap A_\lambda}|f(x)|$ as $A_\lambda$ converging to $\bigcap A_\lambda$? $\bf{How?}$
Here $\displaystyle\sup_{f\in A_\lambda}|f(x)|$ corresponds to the set $A_\lambda$ and is a term of the net $\left\{\displaystyle\sup_{f\in A_\lambda}|f(x)|\right\}_\lambda$.
My attempt: For $A_p\subseteq A_q$ we have $\displaystyle\sup_{f\in A_p}|f(x)|\leq \displaystyle\sup_{f\in A_q}|f(x)|$. Since $A_\lambda$ is monotonically decreasing and $A_\lambda$ converging to $\bigcap A_\lambda$. Thus, $\displaystyle\sup_{f\in A_\lambda}|f(x)|$ converging to $\displaystyle\sup_{f\in \bigcap A_\lambda}|f(x)|$ as $A_\lambda$ converging to $\bigcap A_\lambda$.
Am I rightfully attempted? Or, I have to explain more things? Please let me know. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

The word 'sequence' is used only when the index set is countable. Is your index set $(0,\infty)$ or ${1,2,3...}$?

I don't see how the question  involves Banach spaces and bounded linear functionals.

@geetha290krm thank you for your comment. In particular, linear functional has no role here. But boundedness ensures the existence of supremum. And I am trying to see this thing when the index set is $(0, \infty)$.  I should write it net instead of sequence.

Bounded linear functionals are not bounded!

Yes, you are right. I apologize.

@geetha290krm can you please edit the question and hint at the solution? It will be very much helpful to me.

No, this is not true. Consider $X = \mathbb{R}$, $X^* = \mathbb{R}$, $A_n := [n,\infty)$ and $x = 1$.
Then, $A_n$ is decreasing for $n \to \infty$ and $\bigcap_n A_n = \emptyset$.
However,
$$
\sup_{f \in A_n} f(x) = \infty
$$
does not converge towards
$$
\sup_{f \in \emptyset} f(x) = -\infty.
$$

In my question, I took the supremum over the functionals. But here you took the supremum over the elements of domain of the functionals.

@Tuh: I changed the answer accordingly.

Thank you for your edit. In your answer, am I doing anything wrong if I write $\displaystyle\sup_{f\in\emptyset}f(x)=\infty$?

Yes, this is wrong - or at least - it is not the standard definition of the supremum of the empty set. Moreover, you could also add a fixed real number, like  $\pi$, to the sets $A_n$ and you do not need to take the supremum over the empty set.

Thank you for the clarification. Is the given question true if $\cap_n A_n\neq \emptyset$?

No, this does not help. Just put $\pi$ inside all $A_n$.

I am a little bit confused about the action of $f$. Is it $f(x)=x.a, a\in A_n$, where $.$ means the dot product ?

No, if $f \in \mathbb R$ and $x \in \mathbb R$, we have $f(x) = f \cdot x$. This follows from the identification of $\mathbb R^*$ with $\mathbb R$.

Great. Thank you very much.
